# How to sanitize html string except image url?

Tags: html, ruby, json, sanitize

I'm trying to sanitize an html string, but I want to whitelist image urls.
My code:

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(phrase.meaning, tags: %w(img), attributes: %w(src))
```

This doesn't work, because it deletes all html tags and the value of `src`.

My expected result in a json file:

```json
meaning: "Lorem ipsum.... http://localhost/image1.jpg .... Lorem ipsum"
```

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your question, but there was one part I wasn't entirely clear on. When you mentioned a json file and had the text `meaning: Lorem ipsum....`, were you intending to have a json file as the result, with `meaning` as a name and the "Lorem ipsum...." stuff as a value?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I don't understand you I want have http://localhost:3000/example.json and the result should be meaning: " Some text and included url http://localhost/image1.jpg ... next text". Now I have meaning: "Some text and included url    next text".

Comment: I was verifying that you were wanting the result in a json file. The edit just before mine made it look like the word "meaning" in your answer was a typo that should be taken out. After I commented asking for clarity, I came to the conclusion that the word "meaning" was indeed meant to be part of a json file and so I adjusted my edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to use the [PermitScrubber](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer#railshtmlpermitscrubber) from the same gem directly:

```
html = 'Foo <img src="foo" title="bar"> <a href="foo">bar</a> blob'
scrubber = Rails::Html::PermitScrubber.new
scrubber.tags = ['img']
html_fragment = Loofah.fragment(html)
html_fragment.scrub!(scrubber)
html_fragment.to_s
#=> "Foo <img src=\"foo\" title=\"bar\"> bar blob"
```