# How to parse encoded HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, nokogiri

I'm working on a digest email to send to users of my companies app. For this I'm going through each users emails and trying to find some basic information about each email (from, subject, timestamp, and, the aspect that's causing me difficulty, an image).

I assumed Nokogiri's `search('img')` function would be fine to pull out images. Unfortunately it looks like most emails have a lot of garbage embedded in the URLs of those images, like newlines ("\n"), escape characters ("\"), and the string "3D" for some reason. For example:

```
<img src=3D\"https://=\r\nd3ui957tjb5bqd.cloudfront.net/images/emails/1/logo.png\"
```

This is causing the search to only pull out pieces of the actual URLs/src's:

```
#(Element:0x3fd0c8e83b80 {
  name = "img",
  attributes = [
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e82a28 { name = "src", value = "3D%22https://=" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e82a14 { name = "d3ui957tjb5bqd.cloudfront.net", value = "" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e82a00 { name = "width", value = "3D\"223\"" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e829ec { name = "heigh", value = "t=3D\"84\"" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e829d8 { name = "alt", value = "3D\"Creative" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e829c4 { name = "market", value = "" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fd0c8e829b0 { name = "border", value = "3D\"0\"" })]
  })
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, and how to remove all this junk?

I'm getting decent results from lots of `gsub`'s and safety checks but it feels pretty tacky.

I've also tried `Sanitize.clean` which doesn't work and the PermitScrubber mentioned in "[How to sanitize html string except image url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772712/how-to-sanitize-html-string-except-image-url)".

Comment: As @matt said below, the content is encoded. This isn't a Nokogiri problem, it's the result of the text being wrapped and line continuations being added to fit through old email routers and then be reconstructed. It's for you to notice, determine how to unwind that, then pass the cleaned up text to Nokogiri. You'll find this sort of problem all over the internet, from HTML with embedded HTML that's been encoded multiple times, to badly formatted markup, and unencoded multi-byte characters in multiple languages that will make you crazy. It's life in the internet jungle.

Comment: haha thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mail body is encoded as [quoted printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). You will need to decode the body before you parse it with Nokogiri. You can do this fairly easily with Ruby using [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
decoded = encoded.unpack('M').first
```

You should check what the encoding is by looking at the mail headers before trying to decode, not all mail is encoded this way, and there are other types of encoding.

Comment: Can you provide more information about where the encoding happens? I face the same problem, but the source string is already utf (converted from quated printable, afaiu), so contains stuff like `invitation_token=3Dasdasda`. `unpack` will not work if i understand it correctly, because it works on a "character" basis.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a master in scraping, but you are able to get it through the CSS attribute

```
.at_css("img")['src']
```

For example:

```
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"

doc = open(url_link)
page = Nokogiri::HTML(doc)

page.css("div.col-xs-12.visible-xs.visible-sm div.school-image").each do |pic|
   img = pic.at_css("img")['src'].downcase if pic.at_css("img")
end
```